# Sort digits in single rows in Redshift table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Wanted to know if there is a way to sort digits ascending order in individual rows in a redshift table?
For example,

| number | sorted by asc numbers (result I want) |
| --- | --- |
| 1010101010 | 0000011111 |
| 22442244 | 22224444 |
| 990012 | 001299 |
| 4579321 | 1234579 |

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this

```
   SELECT  REPEAT('0', (LEN(number) - LEN(REPLACE(number, '0', ''))))   +
            REPEAT('1', (LEN(number) - LEN(REPLACE(number, '1', ''))))   +
            REPEAT('2', (LEN(number) - LEN(REPLACE(number, '2', ''))))   +
            REPEAT('3', (LEN(number) - LEN(REPLACE(number, '3', ''))))   +
            REPEAT('4', (LEN(number) - LEN(REPLACE(number, '4', ''))))   +
            REPEAT('5', (LEN(number) - LEN(REPLACE(number, '5', ''))))   +
            REPEAT('6', (LEN(number) - LEN(REPLACE(number, '6', ''))))   +
            REPEAT('7', (LEN(number) - LEN(REPLACE(number, '7', ''))))   +
            REPEAT('8', (LEN(number) - LEN(REPLACE(number, '8', ''))))   +
            REPEAT('9', (LEN(number) - LEN(REPLACE(number, '9', ''))))  
    FROM  table
```

Comment: I was going the route of converting to an array, sort there, and recompose it. However, I think this solution is far simpler.